# The requested URL /en was not found on this server when trying to access front end and admin of sulu-standard

Tags: symfony, sulu

I am trying to get started with sulu as a CMS , and going with the flow of the steps as mentioned in the 'Getting Started' guide , I have setup my virtual server as 'personal' and this is my webspace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webspace xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/webspace/webspace"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/webspace/webspace http://schemas.sulu.io/webspace/webspace-1.0.xsd">

    <name>personal</name>
    <key>personal</key>

    <localizations>
        <localization language="en" default="true"/>
        <localization language="de"/>
    </localizations>

    <theme>
        <key>default</key>
        <default-templates>
            <default-template type="page">default</default-template>
            <default-template type="homepage">overview</default-template>
        </default-templates>

        <error-templates>
            <error-template default="true">ClientWebsiteBundle:views:error.html.twig</error-template>
            <error-template code="404">ClientWebsiteBundle:views:error404.html.twig</error-template>
        </error-templates>
    </theme>

    <navigation>
        <contexts>
            <context key="main">
                <meta>
                    <title lang="de">Hauptnavigation</title>
                    <title lang="en">Mainnavigation</title>
                </meta>
            </context>
        </contexts>
    </navigation>

    <portals>
        <portal>
            <name>personal</name>
            <key>personal</key>
            <resource-locator>
                <strategy>tree</strategy>
            </resource-locator>

            <environments>
                <environment type="prod">
                    <urls>
                        <url>personal/{localization}</url>
                    </urls>
                </environment>
                <environment type="stage">
                    <urls>
                        <url>personal/{localization}</url>
                    </urls>
                </environment>
                <environment type="dev">
                    <urls>
                        <url>personal/{localization}</url>
                    </urls>
                </environment>
            </environments>
        </portal>
    </portals>
</webspace>
```

I have built the dev and the prod version using

```
php app/console sulu:build {env}
```

is there any sulu log I can see , I have made no other changes except the fact that my xml is named as personal.xml. Help ?

When I try to find the routes in the phpcrsh shell , i found a node

```
jcr:primaryType | NAME (15)      | nt:unstructured                      |
jcr:mixinTypes  | NAME (9)       | [0] sulu:path                        |
jcr:uuid        | STRING (36)    | c4419533-8aff-4799-ac89-c8401a84f7e5 |
sulu:history    | BOOLEAN (0)    | false                                |
sulu:content    | REFERENCE (36) | ad186c73-6b01-4d13-8b4e-48b7128b1712 |
sulu:created    | DATE (29)      | 2016-05-29T12:45:13+05:30            |
sulu:changed    | DATE (29)      | 2016-05-29T12:45:13+05:30            |

1 nodes in set (0.000009 sec)
```

Comment: You should only use `php app/console sulu:build dev` or `php app/console sulu:build prod`, depending on in which environment you are. Can you try to navigate to `/cmf/personal/routes/en` in the PHPCR Shell (`php app/console doctrine:phpcr:shell`) and see if there is some data (or if the node exists at all?)

Comment: Yes , I know. The environment which i plan to use is dev . But since I had little idea , and thought that the route would work for prod , i built it for both. I logged into the phpcrsh shell and what i got in the shell is attached to the question

Comment: Can you check the logs in `app/logs/website/dev/dev.log` to see if something bad happens here? Maybe also attach this to the question. Also, on which URL are you accessing the website?